# How to display cross domain json data into html using jquery ajax jsonp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain, jsonp

Hi i have 2 different domain, my json file available in domain1.com and my ajax calling (html) file in domain2.com. Now i am trying to print the following json data into my html page.

```
    [{
    "userID": 506,
    "userName": "Alan",
    "userAge": "alan@somewhere.com",
    "userGender": "male",
    "userNo": 5,
    "userStreet": "abx,street",
    "userCity": "chennai",
    "userCountry": "singapore",
    "userPostal": "545445",
    "userProduct": "samsung",
    "userQty": "4",
    "userPrice": "600"
}, {
    "userID": 566,
    "userName": "bob",
    "userAge": "bob@somewhere.com",
    "userGender": "female",
    "userNo": 8,
    "userStreet": "box,street",
    "userCity": "hydrbad",
    "userCountry": "USA",
    "userPostal": "8787",
    "userProduct": "PIXEL",
    "userQty": "7",
    "userPrice": "3400"
}]
```

i am trying to display the above mentioned json data into my html page using the following code, but i am not getting anything. Anybody can help me in this?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        //alert("hi");
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://stemgy.com/d.json',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function(dataWeGotViaJsonp){
                alert(dataWeGotViaJsonp);
                    var text = '';
                    var len = dataWeGotViaJsonp.length;
                    alert(len);

                }
            });
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='response'></div>
</body>
```

Comment: What is getting logged to the devtools console

Comment: If nothing else works, you can always fall back to using  `$.ajax({ url: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://stemgy.com/d.json'…` (especially for a case like this where you’re not doing any auth or sending anything sensitive in the request).

Comment: hi this is my url - http://bwdcdemo.in/json/test.php in my console nothing i am getting.